# Using chrome 54 console with XPATH query

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-devtools

When I update Chrome 54,I found some problems with the console when I use XPATH query`$x("//input[@name='email']")` it use to give me the HTML elements before the update, after update the query result would be in javascript objects like in the below pic.
[image]

what should I do to get the web elements with XPATH queries?

Comment: I guess `console.log.apply(0, $x("//input[@name='email']"))`

Comment: Thanks for your response and it is working. Could please explain why this effect takes place with chrome v54 and not with v53?

Comment: Broken by https://crrev.com/2120613002/ Feel free to open a new bug report on https://crbug.com

Comment: Bug logged https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660626, thank you

Comment: If you only need to find the selector and not anything else you can also inspect and just use search there using any selector css/xpath by just pasting the selector in the search box.

Comment: Thanks, @wOxxOm for diagnosing (you should add comment as an answer), and thanks bps for filing the bug.  ***Everyone should consider starring  [Issue 660626](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660626) to encourage resolution.***  Thanks.